# Creating a cross-process function pointer

Tags: c++, windows, function-pointers

I have a Visual Studio 2008 C++ project for Windows Mobile 6 with two processes. Both of which I would like to have access to the same function which is contained in process1.

That function is `Buzz`:

```
struct TEST_STRUCT
{
    int bar;
    WCHAR foo[ 20 ];
};

typedef int( *pfn_Buzz )( TEST_STRUCT* );

int Buzz( TEST_STRUCT* info );
```

Process1 contains the definition for `Buzz` and creates a function pointer for it in a memory-mapped file:

```
int Buzz( TEST_STRUCT* info )
{
    info->bar = 1;
    wsprintf( info->foo, L"Hello!" );
    return 100;
}

int _tmain( int argc, _TCHAR* argv[] )
{
    // create a memory-mapped file shared memory space that can be read by any process
    HANDLE mapping = ::CreateFileMapping( INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, sizeof( pfn_Buzz ) , NULL );
    LPVOID buzz_addr = ::MapViewOfFile( mapping, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, sizeof( pfn_Buzz ) );

    // find our process' memory offset
    DWORD offset = ::GetCurrentProcessIndex() + 0x02000000;

    // copy the complete function address to the shared memory space
    buzz_addr = ( LPVOID )( ( DWORD )&Buzz + offset );

    // convert the function address to a string to send to process2.exe
    WCHAR address[ 9 ] = { 0 };
    wsprintf( address, L"%x", ( ( DWORD )buzz_addr ) );

    // start process2.exe and wait for it to finish
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = { 0 };
    ::CreateProcess( L"\\test_user.exe", address, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, &pi );
    ::WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );

    ::UnmapViewOfFile( buzz_addr );
    ::CloseHandle( mapping );

    return 0;
}
```

Process2 receives the address for `Buzz` from Process1, casts it to the `pfn_Buzz` function pointer, and executes it.

```
// process2.exe
int _tmain( int argc, _TCHAR* argv[] )
{
    // get the address of the Buzz() function pointer
    WCHAR* wszAddr = argv[ 1 ];
    WCHAR* wszAddrEnd = &argv[ 1 ][ 8 ];
    DWORD address = wcstol( wszAddr, &wszAddrEnd, 16 );
    pfn_Buzz PFNBuzz = ( pfn_Buzz )address;

    // execute buzz
    TEST_STRUCT test = { 0 };
    PFNBuzz( &test );

    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, I get an Illegal Instruction exception in process2 when I try to execute the `PFNBuzz` function.

Can anybody suggest what I could change to get the functionality I'm after?

Thanks,
PaulH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want both processes to use the same function, put the function into a DLL and link that DLL to both processes. Each process has its own address space, so an address in one process may not work at all in another process, and even if it "works" it'll be pointing to something completely different.

Although you're taking/passing the offset into the memory mapped region on the parent side, I don't see any matching code to map the same region and add its base to the pointer when you try to access it on the client side.

Visual C++ has a `__based` pointer type that can simplify this a bit.

Comment: Is there no way to copy the function code to a shared address space?

Comment: @PaulH: it's *possible* to do so on your own, but a DLL does it completely automatically. Unless the DLL needs to access data in one process, it's a lot simpler (and if it does need to access data, it's generally better to put that data into the DLL and make it shared -- see `#pragma data_set` for details about how to do that).

Comment: did you mean `#pragma data_seg`? I don't see a `data_set` on MSDN.

Comment: @PaulH: Yup -- in this case the 't' apparently stands for "typo". :-|

Comment: Can you go in to a little more detail on the suggestion in your edit about mapping the region on the client side?

Comment: @PaulH: on the parent side, you're creating a file mapping, mapping a view of the file, and then passing the offset within that view. On the client side, you need to open the file mapping, map the view, then add the base of the mapping to the offset you received.

Answer (score 6):

Your problem arises from the fact that Process A (Which starts Process B) have 2 totally different virtual address spaces.  You can pass a function pointer to Process A but seeeing as their address spaces are different any pointer you pass will be meaining less to another process.  this is one of the huge bonuses of processes.

If you wish to communicate between processes then you will need to use some form of [Inter-Process Communication (IPC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication).

There are several ways of doing [IPC under windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365574%28VS.85%29.aspx).  In my opinion the most versatile method is by using sockets.  Sockets give you the advantage that you can seperate the machines running Process A and Process B and still get the functionality you want.  Equally there is nothing stopping both processes running on the same machine.  The flexibility it provides is very useful though.

So assuming you choose a socket based method of IPC then what you are effectively doing is a [Remote Procedure Call (RPC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call).

There are, as you can probably imagine, loads of different ways of doing RPC.  You could use [DCOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_Component_Object_Model) or [Corba](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corba).  [Raknet](http://www.jenkinssoftware.com/raknet/index.html) is a third party library that supports RPC.  There are numerous other solutions as well.  I strongly recommend doing a load of research into the matter.  The links and keywords I've provided you with should give you a good starting point :)

Comment: Memory mapped files are a method of IPC in Windows CE. Also, I provided the process-slot corrected virtual memory address of the function to account for the differences in virtual address space.

Comment: @PaulH:  You are only mapping in one process though(and not even named mapping at that!) so, sure it can be used but i suggest you read this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366878(v=VS.85).aspx Also note that you are not taking into account address space randomization.  Either follow the above link carefully or use a different method ...

Comment: I knew Win 7 and Vista use address randomization. I did not know windows mobile 6 did. Do you have an MSDN link describing it?

Comment: @PaulH: Off the top of my head i don't know whether it does.  However such things should always be beared in mind.  As it is you are creating a mapping in one process and NOT openining it in another process therefore they do not get the same address space.  As I say ... read the link in my previous comment and implement it carefully.  Failing that try another method of RPC.

Comment: @PaulH: Furthermore file mapping does not  give 2 things the same address in the virtual address space.  It, simply, synchronises the cacheing on the 2 so that a change to the "file" on one process is instantly reflected in the other process.  Thus, regardless, passing a function as you have done will NOT work.  Example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366551(v=VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 3):

You can simply export the function using `__declspec(dllexport)` and then load it using `GetProcAddress()` using it's name. If in C++, just remember to `extern "C"` the declaration to disable name mangling. Consider:

```
extern "C" int __declspec(dllexport) Buzz( TEST_STRUCT* info ) { ... }
int main ( int, char ** )
{
    pfn_Buzz buzz = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(NULL), "Buzz");
    // ...
}
```

Then, pass the function name using the IPC method of your choice.

Comment: Assuming that Buzz is present in used by both processes. eg. through the use of a common DLL as suggested by Jerry Coffin.

Comment: I was assuming this was a fork-type thing where the process re-spawned the same executable. If loading through a common DLL, the module handle would of course be the one obtained by a call to `LoadLibrary()`.